# onclick in php echo with error invalid unexpected token

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to add the onclick funtion when user checked the check box, and then the total price will be shown.
All the information including price is retrieve from database (no problem with retrieving data, the data display correctly).
Here is how's the code looks like.

```js
//calculate price
function total() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('event');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
}
var checks = document.getElementsByName(event);
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = total;
```

```html
<form id="bookingForm" action="javascript:alert('form submitted');" method="get">
  <section id="selectEvent">
   <h2>Select Events</h2>
    <div class ="item">
    <span class="chosen">
   event1 <input type= checkbox name= event data-price = "1" value=eventId1/>
    event2 <input type= checkbox name= event data-price = "2" value=eventId2/>
   </span>
   </div>
  </section>

 

  <section id="checkCost">
   <h2>Total cost</h2>
   Total <input type="text" name="total"  size="10" readonly />
  </section>

 
 </form>
```

here is the java script code,just focus on funtion total()

```
window.addEventListener('load', initialise);

    function initialise () {
        'use strict';
        //calculate price
        function total(){
        var cal= document.getElementsByName('event[]');
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i<cal.length; i++){
            if(cal[i].checked){
                total += parseFloat(cal[i].data-price);
            }
        }           
    document.getElementByName("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
    }
```

here is the link for my reference

[1]: [Display total price when checkbox clicked in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825477/display-total-price-when-checkbox-clicked-in-js) 
i also tried but it doesn't work

> total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price")

Comment: You have edited the question - but now the original code is gone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline the event handler!

Also getElementsByName is plural and returns a collection:

`document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value`

Remove the inline event and instead use

```js
//calculate price
function total() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
var checks = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = total;
```

If you do not use total anywhere else, do

```
var checks = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = function() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = function() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div class='item'>
  <span class='eventTitle'>title 1</span>
  <span class='eventStartDate'>1-1-2018</span>
  <span class='eventEndDate'>2-2-2018</span>
  <span class='catDesc'>Event 1</span>
  <span class='venueName'>Place 1</span>
  <span class='eventPrice'>100</span>
  <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='id1' data-price='100' /></span>
</div>
<div class='item'>
  <span class='eventTitle'>title 2</span>
  <span class='eventStartDate'>2-2-2018</span>
  <span class='eventEndDate'>3-3-2018</span>
  <span class='catDesc'>Event 2</span>
  <span class='venueName'>Place 2</span>
  <span class='eventPrice'>200</span>
  <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='id1' data-price='200' /></span>
</div>
<section id="checkCost">
  <h2>Total cost</h2>
  Total <input type="text" name="total"  size="10" readonly />
 </section>
```

Comment: Sir, it still doesn't work, what i do is remove the onclick = total() and then add your code to the following function. 

'function total(){
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('event[]');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i<cal.length; i++){
   if(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price").checked){
    total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
   }
  }   
 
 var checks = document.getElementsByName('event[]'); 
 for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) checks[i].onclick=total;
 }'

Comment: Also you have another error `if (cal[i].checked) {` not `if(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price").checked)`

Comment: Appreciated but when i checked on the checke box, nothing happen, no error show on the console too.

Comment: Please use the `<>` snippet editor in your question and post the view source of at least two checkboxes, the total field and the JavaScript

Comment: See my snippet - you need to add the total to the total field

Comment: It is `document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);`  it is not singular

Comment: i had studied your code and try to understand how it works. first. assign an onclick function on to `checks`. it is a for loop because it can be always checked or unchecked, and can be select multiple time. After `checks`  have the onclick function, then carry out the calculation in `cal`. lastly, display the cost by finding there name `total` . I not really understand why there is a `[0]`   in `document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total;` but it couldn't work without it.
Am i correctly explained how your code works ?

Comment: I use a for loop to assign the same click handler to all checkboxes. I need [0] because getElementsByName returns a collection with one element and I need the first and only one

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use so much '\' ? and what the asterisks '*' after `total()` for?
I have tried following snippet and it seems to works well.
(only changing the echo line in your php code)

```
echo "\t<div class='item'>
            <span class='eventTitle'>".filter_var($event['eventTitle'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS)."</span>
            <span class='eventStartDate'>{$event['eventStartDate']}</span>
            <span class='eventEndDate'>{$event['eventEndDate']}</span>
            <span class='catDesc'>{$event['catDesc']}</span>
            <span class='venueName'>{$event['venueName']}</span>
            <span class='eventPrice'>{$event['eventPrice']}</span>
            <span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]' value='{$event['eventID']}' data-price='{$event['eventPrice']}' onclick='total()*'/></span>
      </div>\n";
```

Comment: the '\' is used to string escape, when i remove it, it's gv me total() is not a function.