# javascript get element by ID within ID

Tags: javascript

I would like to calculate the total price of the  if check box is checked by using JavaScript 
I'm not allow to separate the id to 2 section of by adding div
for example.

```
<form id="bookingForm">

 <section id = "checkcost">
      <h2>Total cost</h2>
     Total <input type="text" name="total" value="$0.00" size="10" readonly />
 </section>

</form>
```

First, i use this method get the id

> var frm = document.getElementById('bookingForm')

i m  trying to do by using the following code but this is not the correct method

> frm.checkcost.total = calculate()

Since the input area to shows the total cost is inside the id="bookingForm", how should i display the total cost once the check box is checked?? 
ps:  here is the link i had try but it didn't work, and now i'm trying other method

[onclick in php echo with error invalid unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179973/onclick-in-php-echo-with-error-invalid-unexpected-token)

Comment: Give the input an id and just grab it directly `document.getElementById('myTextInput') = "Something";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's only one field named `total` in the form, you don't need to worry about the section at all:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
frm.total = calculate();
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#bookingForm [name=total]").value = calculate();
```

---

If you have multiple fields named `total`, then you just use the ID of the section:

```
document.querySelector("#checkcost [name=total]").value = calculate();
// ----------------------^
```

---

`document.querySelector` finds the first element that matches a given CSS selector. You can use the full power of CSS to find elements in the document. There's also `document.querySelectorAll` which finds a *list* of matching elements. Finally, individual elements also have both methods, which look only within those elements. So for instance, we could also do this:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
frm.querySelector("#checkcost [name=total]").value = calculate();
```

(But that's just an example, not a suggestion; it's more round-about than necessary.)